# How to send parameters in json format to http get method, Node.js?

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I am developing a REST api using node.js, it's express module. I want to send my request parameters in the json format to express object get method. How I can achieve this?

```
var express        = require('express');
var app            = express();

app.get('/', function(request, response){
  console.log(request.body);      // your JSON
  response.send(request.body);    // echo the result back
  });
```

Comment: GET request has no body, so if you want to pass json as a parameter, you need to transfer encoded via URL: `http://example.com/api/?json=encoded.uri(json.stringify)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to test your api,  [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) will do what you want.

For example:

```
var request = require('request');
var options = {
    url : 'http://www.somedomain.com/',
    json : true,
    body : {
       some : 'json',
       goes : 'here'
    },
    method : 'post'
};
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // Show the HTML for the Google homepage. 
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var request = require('request');

request.post(
    'http://www.yoursite.com/formpage',
    { form: { key: 'value' } },
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body)
        }
    }
);
```